# Unable to boot normally on Lenovo Legion 5 15ACH6H

Tags: boot, lenovo, 23.04

It's been almost 3 years since I bought my Lenovo Legion 5 15ACH6H, and I finally took the decision to switch to Ubuntu, I was able to create a bootable USB stick with Ubuntu 23.04, but I'm unable to boot normally, I need to use safe graphics, or GNOME will never finish to load. Do I need to change a setting somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't interfere with the core functionality of the Ubuntu installer if it is using safe graphics. If you can install Ubuntu when the Ubuntu installer is using safe graphics, your new installation of Ubuntu should be OK after the installation is finished and you reboot into Ubuntu.